# Oracle partition by range

Tags: oracle, partition

I have a table `orders` with column  `order_date`. And I want to add partition `partition by range`*(for every month)* for `order_date`. there are two statuses New and Completed in orders. Only new orders can be updated. If i update `order_date` often, can it strongly decrease speed of update than usual when update from one month to another month?
I also need partition by order_date to work with only current month orders.
What would be best way to use partition?

Comment: i would say, if `action_date` is a column, that you update very often, you should't use is as partition key

Comment: But,I need to this for select statement

Comment: you can do select  without a Partition, or why are you Need a partion for select?

Comment: i have updated my question, can you see it?